# Is NLP likely to be sufficiently solved in the next few years?

Tags: natural-language-processing

The reason I am asking this question is because I am about to start a PhD in NLP. So I am wondering if there would be as much job opportunities in research in industry as oppose to in academia in the future (~ 5 to 10 years) or would it be mostly a matter of using a library off the shelf. I have done some research and it seems NLP is AI-complete, which means it's probably a problem that will be "solved" only when AGI is solved , but still I would appreciate any input.

Comment: You should directly talk and ask advice to your possible advisors. They will probably give you a better overview of the state of affairs of the field. This question seems to be primarily opinion-based, so it should be closed here. Maybe you can reformulate it in such a way that it can be answered unambiguously.

Comment: @Ash a little side note: without a doubt, NLP will be a research topic in 5 years. granted you can get a lot of utility of taking something off the shelf but there are still many weaknesses to these models and unknown characterstics. It is *far* from solved

Comment: Apologies.  This is a valid question, just not well suited for this Stack.  I'm closing provisionally, but **I think there is a valid question here: "IS NLP likely to be sufficiently solved in the next few years?"**.  (Feel free to revise and submit for re-opening.  By reformulating the question to be suitable for this stack, you should be able to get the info you're looking for.)